# How to create a custom notification (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm making an inventory app in Android Studio and I need some help with a custom notification function.

I want to create a notification system that outputs a notification when the user has no items in their inventory. I have coded a basic function for notifications, but I can't seem to figure out how to output the notification when all items in the inventory have been destroyed.

I'm not sure if I should be calling my notification method in the DisplayInventory class or my database class.

Any help is much appreciated!

**This is the code for my DisplayInventory screen. This runs most of the functionality**

```
public class DisplayInventory extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Setting up all my objects from the display inventory layout, Database Helper and Adapter
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    Button mAdd_button;
    MyDBHelper myDatabase;
    UserPermission notification;
    ArrayList<String> itemId;
    ArrayList<String> itemName;
    ArrayList<String> itemOwner;
    ArrayList<String> numItem;
    InventoryAdapter inventoryAdapter;
    TextView mLonelyInventory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_inventory);

        //Instantiating necessary objects from the layout for functionality
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLonelyInventory = findViewById(R.id.LonelyInventory);
        mAdd_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);

        //On Click listener that will take users from the display inventory screen to add new item screen
        mAdd_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayInventory.this, AddItem.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Instantiating ArrayLists that will be used to hold information from the DB
        myDatabase = new MyDBHelper(DisplayInventory.this);
        itemId = new ArrayList<>();
        itemName = new ArrayList<>();
        itemOwner = new ArrayList<>();
        numItem = new ArrayList<>();

        InsertDataToArray();

        inventoryAdapter = new InventoryAdapter(DisplayInventory.this, this, itemId, itemName, itemOwner, numItem);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(inventoryAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DisplayInventory.this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            recreate();
        }
    }

    //This function uses cursors to help move data into the arrays we set up
    //setVisibility() lets me show some text when the inventory is empty
    void InsertDataToArray() {
        Cursor cursor = myDatabase.readAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            mLonelyInventory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                itemId.add(cursor.getString(0));
                itemName.add(cursor.getString(1));
                itemOwner.add(cursor.getString(2));
                numItem.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
            mLonelyInventory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

**This is the code for my database**

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Setting up all variables that make up the columns in the database.
    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "InventoryList.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_list";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "item_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_OWNER = "item_owner";
    private static final String COLUMN_NUM = "item_num";


    MyDBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    //Initializing the Database
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String query =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_OWNER + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_NUM + " INTEGER);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);



    }

    @Override
    //This will make sure to erase the table if one already exists.
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    //This method is adding functionality to add the item name, owner and number of items.
    void addItem(String itemName, String itemOwner, int numItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, itemName);
        cv.put(COLUMN_OWNER, itemOwner);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NUM, numItem);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Added to Inventory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //PENDING: May not need this toast message. AFTER MAIN SCREEN RETURN FUNCTION ADDED
        }
    }

    //This method sets up the functionality to search the entire database and read the data.
    Cursor readAllData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;

        if (db != null) {
           cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    //This method allows the user to update the item's data. Values that will be updated are item name, owner and number of items.
    void updateData(String row_id, String item_name, String item_owner, String item_num) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, item_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_OWNER, item_owner);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NUM, item_num);
        long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});

//        if (result == -1) {
//            Toast.makeText(context, "Well, that didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //PENDING: May not need this toast message.
//        }
//        else {
//            Toast.makeText(context, "The Update was a Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //PENDING: May not need this toast message.
//        }
    }

    void deleteItem(String row_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});

//        if (result == -1) {
//            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Could Not Be Deleted! It's Still Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //PENDING: May not need this toast message.
//        }
//        else {
//            Toast.makeText(context, "The Data is No More!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   //PENDING: May not need this toast message.
//        }
    }

    void destroyInventory() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

}
```

**This is the code where I have tried to set up notifications**

```
public class UserPermission extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mUserPermission;
    private int notificationId = 1;
    MyDBHelper myDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_permission);

        mUserPermission = findViewById(R.id.userPermission);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Channel ID", "My Channel ID", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


    }

    public void userPermission(View view) {
        givePermission();
    }


    public void inventoryNotification() {
        // NEW CODE ADDED HERE
        String NotificationMessage = "No inventory Items!";
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(UserPermission.this, "My Channel ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications)
                .setContentTitle("Inventory Notification")
                .setContentText(NotificationMessage)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        //.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(UserPermission.this);
        managerCompat.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: if you know about live data ,use observer to send notification if inventory is empty in DisplayInventory  Activity.

Comment: @androidLearner I never knew about live data, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this problem after asking the question.

Instead of creating a separate class that holds the notification functionality, I instead Implemented the notification functionality in the DisplayInventory class.

I first created a channel in onCreate()

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Channel ID", "My Channel ID", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

I then placed the code for the notification in the InsertDataToArray() method and checked if the database was empty. If so, the notification displays.

```
void InsertDataToArray() {
        Cursor cursor = myDatabase.readAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            mLonelyInventory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //ADDING NEW CODE HERE
            String NotificationMessage = "No items in Inventory!";
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(DisplayInventory.this, "My Channel ID")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications)
                    .setContentTitle("Inventory Notification")
                    .setContentText(NotificationMessage)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(DisplayInventory.this);
            managerCompat.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
            //NEW CODE ENDS HERE
        }
```